# Using PIVOT to get SELECT into one column, not row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a select, which would show the result into ONE column, not row. I tried using `PIVOT`, but I am not successful at all.

Result of my select:

```
Customer_ID:   InsertionDate:  Name:   Birth:                                                
  1234          2020-01-01     John  1993-01-01
```

I want to have it like this:

```
                 MyColumn                                               
 Customer_ID:    1234   
 InsertionDate:  2020-01-01  
 Name:           John  
 Birth:          1993-01-01
```

Comment: What you're doing here isn't pivoting, it's unpivoting. With the data you have, however, doing this is a bad idea. `Customer_ID` is clearly an `int` and `[Name]` a `varchar`, and you can't have 2 different data types in the same column. Looks like you have a problem with `InsertionDate` too, which looks like it's a `varchar`, due to it having the format `dd.MM.yyyy` where as your other column, `Birth`, appears to be a `date`. What you want to do here is a bad idea, and you really need to fix your data type of `InsertionDate`. According to your data, `12.1.2020` is **before** `27.12.2018`.

Comment: Hi Larnu,

I am sorry, the both Brith and Insertion dates are of course DATE. Its just my mistake, I wrote the date in incorrect format. 
So Customer_ID = INT, Both dates: DATE, Name: Varchar

Comment: Also honestly I dont think I do care about the datatypes here. I can just convert everything to Varchar, because I will not work with the data after this select anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to obtain a single column:

```
declare @test table (Customer_ID int,  InsertionDate date,  Name varchar(50), Birth date)   
insert into @test values (1234, '2020-01-01','John', '1993-01-01')

select  val as MyColumn
from @test
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    VALUES
        ('Customer_ID:'+   cast(Customer_ID as varchar)),
        ('InsertionDate:'+ cast(InsertionDate as varchar)),
        ('Name:'+ cast(Name as varchar)),
        ('Birth:'+ cast(Birth as varchar))
    )CS (val)
```

results:

[image]

or, if you prefer having a separate column for descriptions:

```
select 
    Col as ColumnName, 
    val as MyColumn
from @test
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
    VALUES
        ('Customer_ID:'  , cast(Customer_ID as varchar)),
        ('InsertionDate:', cast(InsertionDate as varchar)),
        ('Name:'         , cast(Name as varchar)),
        ('Birth:'        , cast(Birth as varchar))
    )CS (col, val)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Aaaaand we have a winner :-) Thank you so much, Andrea!